# How to create an additional GUID partition on a GPT disk, using Diskpart, in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, gpt, diskpart

I have Windows 10 installed on on a GPT disk. This is the current partition layout:

- Partition 1: 499 MB (Recovery)
- Partition 2: 99 MB (System)
- Partition 3: 16 MB (MSR)
- Partition 4: 320 GB (Primary - drive letter C:)
- Unallocated Space: 610 GB

What is the right way to create an additional GUID partition, to fill the unused 610 GB? Preferably using the *DiskPart* command line utility.

There is plenty of material on the internet on converting MBR disks to GPT, but I'm struggling to find a simple example of how to add another GUID partition to unallocated space on an existing GPT disk.

I'm also confused about what GUID partition "ID" is required to create a normal partition that I can format and mount as drive D: like I used to back in the old-school MBR days.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just create another partition. You can do that from diskpart if you want or any number of partition managers including the built-in one.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax to use in DiskPart to create the additional GUID partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm struggling to find a simple example of how to add another GUID partition to unallocated space on an existing GPT disk.

That's because it's no different from adding a partition on an existing MBR disk.

You keep using the term "GUID partition" as if it was some special kind. It's not. To create a new partition on a GPT-partitioned disk, you *just create a partition* using whatever partitioning tool you find most convenient. (Assuming, of course, a modern tool with GPT support.)

The only differences are positive – you don't need to make the "primary vs logical" decision because there's only one kind, and choosing the right partition type is a bit simpler even without prior knowledge because there aren't as many oddball special-case types as MBR had.

(Although a good partitioning tool should automatically offer the correct partition type ID for general usage, just like they already do so for MBR-partitioned disks...)

> What is the right way to create an additional GUID partition, to fill the unused 610 GB? Preferably using the DiskPart command line utility.

In DiskPart, use `create partition primary`. (Although GPT does not have the primary/logical split, Windows uses the term to mean a generic partition on all disk types.)

In Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc), right-click the unallocated area, then select "New Simple Volume".

From a Linux system you can use `gdisk` (gptfdisk), or a recent version of `fdisk` from util-linux – in both, use the `n` command. It's still recommended to use Windows to *format* the partition as NTFS, though.

> I'm also confused about what GUID partition "ID" is required to create a normal partition that I can format and mount as drive D:

The partition type is `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`, also known as [Microsoft Basic Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition).

You do not need to enter it when using Windows' tools; it will be selected automatically when creating a "regular" partition ("primary" in diskpart, "simple volume" in diskmgmt).

When using Linux gdisk, the "short ID" is `0700`, or you can paste the full GUID anyway.